# Role not being found even though exists in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

Can anybody explain to me why when updating my role when I debug through the code it has the correct `Guid` for the user and group?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(RoleModification model)
{
        IdentityResult result;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (string userId in model.AddIds ?? new string[] { })
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,
                        model.RoleName);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        AddErrorsFromResult(result);
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (string userId in model.DeleteIds ?? new string[] { })
            {
                ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    result = await userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user,
                        model.RoleName);
                    if (!result.Succeeded)
                    {
                        AddErrorsFromResult(result);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        else
        {
            return await Update(model.RoleId);
        }
  }
```

This the `[dbo].[AspNetRoles]` roles table as you can see `ClubSuperAdmin` does exist.

| ID | NAME | NormalizedName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2924519a-7024-417f-a8e1-335dca7dba63 | ClubMod | CLUBMOD |
| 3f6e4213-d513-47ae-8e02-dcdeaa4e22c9 | ClubUser | CLUBUSER |
| 40ff2868-3264-4195-82c4-68bddcc5b036 | ClubSuperAdmin | SUPERADMIN |
| 4b1b831c-61ac-46b9-88f5-089a11f1e46e | Admin | ADMIN |

User Table:

| ID | Firstname | Last Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| f2ab370a-329a-4fde-989f-f3526334de1a | David | User |

[image]

So why is it saying that the `InvalidOperationException: Role CLUBSUPERADMIN does not exist`, surley it knows the upercase of `ClubSuperAdmin` is the name?

> ### AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string role)
> Warehouse.Web.Controllers.RoleController.Update(RoleModification
> model) in RoleController.cs
>
> ```
>         {
>             foreach (string userId in model.AddIds ?? new string[] { })
>             {
>                 ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
>                 if (user != null)
>                 {
>                     result = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user,
>                         model.RoleName);
>                     if (!result.Succeeded)
>                     {
>                         AddErrorsFromResult(result);
>                     }
>                 }
> ```
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor+TaskOfIActionResultExecutor
> ?.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, object controller, object[]
> arguments) System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask.get_Result()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that the role `CLUBSUPERADMIN` does not exist and, looking at the table, that item is not there in the `NormalizedName` column. I am going to assume that the original name of that role was `SuperAdmin` and someone changed the table manually but didn't also update the `NormalizedName` value too. To fix this, fix that value, e.g.:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
SET NormalizedName = 'CLUBSUPERADMIN'
WHERE NAME = 'ClubSuperAdmin'
```

Comment: sometimes we just have those moments